# Excel Custom function : TypeError: Network request failed on windows Desktop, working online and mac (desktop & online)

Tags: office-js, office-addins, custom-functions-excel

Implemented excel addin custom functions which are working in online version (windows/mac) and desktop version (MAC) . Custom functions are failing in windows desktop version.

Verified the desktop office build number and it's supported as per the Microsoft docs.

Each implemented custom function will invoke a server call.

Further debugging got the "TypeError: Network request failed" error. Not sure why it's failing only in windows desktop excel.

Following in the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp 
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/
    1.0"
  xmlns:ov=
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>0e97108b-0e3b-484c-9ee8-24c4ac0e0eb8</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>CFS</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="CFS"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="CFS functions"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/FS- 
   Favicon.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl 
    DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/FS-Favicon.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.cfs.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
   <AppDomain>https://www.cfs.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
   <Host Name="Workbook"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
   <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
   <Set Name="CustomFunctionsRuntime" MinVersion="1.1"/>
  </Sets>
</Requirements>
<DefaultSettings>
   <SourceLocation 
    DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
 </DefaultSettings>
 <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
 <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
  <Hosts>
  <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
    <!-- <Runtimes>    
      <Runtime resid="CFS.Functions.Url" lifetime="long" />
    </Runtimes> -->
    <AllFormFactors>
      <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomFunctions">
        <Script>
          <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Script.Url"/>
        </Script>
        <Page>
          <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Page.Url"/>
        </Page>
        <Metadata>
          <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Metadata.Url"/>
        </Metadata>
        <Namespace resid="Functions.Namespace"/>
      </ExtensionPoint>
    </AllFormFactors>
    <DesktopFormFactor>
      <GetStarted>
        <Title resid="GetStarted.Title"/>
        <Description resid="GetStarted.Description"/>
        <LearnMoreUrl resid="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
      </GetStarted>
      <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
      <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
        <CustomTab id="CFS.Tab">
          <Group id="CFS.Tab1.Group1">
            <Label resid="CFS.Tab1.GroupLabel" />
            <Icon>
              <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
              <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
              <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
            </Icon>
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="CFS.FunctionsButton">
              <!-- <OverriddenByRibbonApi>true</OverriddenByRibbonApi> -->
              <!-- <Enabled>false</Enabled> -->
              <Label resid="CFS.FunctionsButton.Label" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="CFS.FunctionsButton.Label"/>
                <Description resid="CFS.FunctionsButton.Tooltip"/>
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="functions.16x16"/>
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="functions.32x32"/>
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="functions.80x80"/>
              </Icon>
              <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                <SourceLocation resid="CFS.Functions.Url"/>
              </Action>
            </Control>  
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="CFS.AccountButton">
              <Label resid="CFS.AccountButton.Label" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="CFS.AccountButton.Label"/>
                <Description resid="CFS.AccountButton.Tooltip"/>
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="account-management.16x16"/>
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="account-management.32x32"/>
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="account-management.80x80"/>
              </Icon>
              <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                <FunctionName>manageAccount</FunctionName>
              <!-- <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane"> -->
                <!-- <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId> -->
                <!-- <SourceLocation resid="CFS.Account.Url"/> -->
              </Action>
            </Control>
          </Group>
          <Label resid="CFS.Tab.TabLabel" />
        </CustomTab>
        <!-- <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
          <Group id="CommandsGroup">
            <Label resid="CommandsGroup.Label"/>
            <Icon>
              <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
              <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
              <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
            </Icon>
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton">
              <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
              </Icon>
              <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
              </Action>
            </Control>
          </Group>
        </OfficeTab> -->
      </ExtensionPoint>
    </DesktopFormFactor>
  </Host>
</Hosts>
<Resources>
  <bt:Images>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>

    <bt:Image id="functions.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/functions-16.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="functions.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/functions-16.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="functions.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/functions-16.png"/>

    <bt:Image id="account-management.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/account-management-16.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="account-management.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/account-management-16.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="account-management.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/account-management-16.png"/>
  </bt:Images>
  <bt:Urls>
    <bt:Url id="Functions.Script.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/dist/functions.js"/>
    <bt:Url id="Functions.Metadata.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/dist/functions.json"/>
    <bt:Url id="Functions.Page.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/dist/functions.html"/>
    <bt:Url id="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812"/>
    <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
    
    <!-- <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/> -->
    <bt:Url id="CFS.Functions.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/dist/cfs.html"/>
    <bt:Url id="CFS.Account.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/dist/cfs-auth-management.html"/>
  </bt:Urls>
  <bt:ShortStrings>
    <bt:String id="Functions.Namespace" DefaultValue="CFS"/>
    <bt:String id="GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="CFS add-in!"/>
    <!-- <bt:String id="CommandsGroup.Label" DefaultValue="Commands Group"/> -->

    <bt:String id="CFS.Tab.TabLabel" DefaultValue="CFS"/>
    <bt:String id="CFS.Tab1.GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Manage CFS"/>
    <bt:String id="CFS.FunctionsButton.Label" DefaultValue="Insert Functions"/>
    <bt:String id="CFS.AccountButton.Label" DefaultValue="Manage Account"/>
  </bt:ShortStrings>
  <bt:LongStrings>
    <bt:String id="GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Loaded succesfully."/>
    <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane"/>

    <bt:String id="CFS.FunctionsButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to view functions"/>
    <bt:String id="CFS.AccountButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Manage Account"/>
  </bt:LongStrings>
</Resources>
```

Any help, why it's only failing only in windows desktop office excel.

Comment: Did you notice any error? May you please share the desktop Excel version (Excel->Account->About Excel)? It would be great if you can share the manifest file which is much helpful for debugging.

Comment: Windows excel version 2104 (Build 13929.20296). Updated the description with manifest. No errors.

Comment: On further debugging, "TypeError: Network request failed" error is blocking this functionality. Not sure why only this is happening in windows desktop excel.

Comment: Looks like your local loopback is disabled. You'll need to enable a local loopback exception. Details please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/cannot-open-add-in-from-localhost

Comment: It didn't worked. The issue seems to be with CORS request in excel custom functions. Trying to implement sharedRuntime as stated at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime.

Comment: @xiaochun I've shared you the git repos (one with shared runtime and other w/o). Can you please test the "https://github.com/avinashmadireddy/ui-less-custom-func-wo_sr". I've created an issue with details as well.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late to answer this post, but I'm new to this myself and I had the exact same error. To fix this problem I changed from 'CustomFunctionsRuntime' to 'SharedRuntime' by following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime.

According to other people this will give some limits to your custom functions, but I didn't notice any right away and solved even other problem I had such as not having a TextDecoder. It's probably too late help you, but I hope I can help other people with the same problem.

Kind regards
Sven